# how to combine two variables data into two rows in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, transpose, sas-macro, proc

We have three variables in sas dataset  and we want to create a new variable which would have values transposed for 2 variables and the third remain as it is.

Eg:

```
Acct_nb repl_acct_nb amount
12334       45678     100
23456       .         200
```

Output needed:

```
 new_acct_nb amount
 12334       100
 45678       100
 23456       200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Since, it is only 2 variables, no need for array logic.

```
data have;
input Acct_nb repl_acct_nb amount;
datalines;
12334 45678 100 
23456 .     200 
;

data want(keep =  new_acct_nb amount);
   set have;
   new_acct_nb = Acct_nb;
   if new_acct_nb then output;
   new_acct_nb = repl_acct_nb;
   if new_acct_nb then output;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do an array-based transposition as follows

```
data want(keep=new_acct_nb amount);
  attrib new_acct_nb length=8;
  set have;
  array account acct_nb repl_acct_nb;
  do over account;
    if missing(account) then continue;
    new_acct_nb = account;
    output;
  end;
run;
```